# Add expiration to SPS page in SPS2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, expiration, jobs

We have existing SharePoint site developed a year back.

Currently, we are planning to add a page (Internal Job Posting page) that would allow to add any new jobs with expiration period.

Please suggest how can I do it in SharePoint 2013 (ON prem)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to then use the SharePoint Announcements List.

1. Create a Announcements List in your site -
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768316.aspx

   2. Add the announcements list view webpart you created in your sharepoint page "Internal Job Posting" .
   3. Configure to display only items that are not expired by editing the web part properties of the added web part in the page.

Link to How to do :[Create Announcements](http://www.portalintegrators.com/how-to-create-announcements-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Arvind, thanks for the response. We are after a solution that allows users to add items on the job site with an expiration date.

Also, the form should pull the following information:
1. Position (heading) 
2. Position number 
3. Closing date (format is Day, date month e.g. Wednesday 10 February) 
4. Salary 
5. Status 
6. Description (allow formatting) 
7. Apply Now (button on public website, though can be a link to the online form if not possible)